# Facebook FQL nested SELECT field value

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

If I have a query with nested query:

```
SELECT name, start_time FROM event WHERE creator IN (SELECT page_id, name FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "59.436961", "24.753575") < 100) LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "JOIN THE CLUB – JAMES WERTS LIVE", 
      "start_time": "2014-06-29T23:00:00+0300"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I have a name of the event, but how can I get "name" field in my query from the "place" table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you would do:

```
SELECT event.name, place.name FROM event, place
```

But FQL is quite limited and lets you either do `SELECT ... FROM event` or `SELECT ... FROM place`.

So in your case, you are not able to get the place name from the `place` table, but you could get the `host` field from the `event` table, which contains the same information:

```
SELECT name, start_time, host
  FROM event  
 WHERE creator IN 
   (SELECT page_id
      FROM place 
     WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "59.436961", "24.753575") < 100) 
 LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "JOIN THE CLUB – JAMES WERTS LIVE", 
      "start_time": "2014-06-29T23:00:00+0300", 
      "host": "Venus Club"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Shame on me, I didn't figured that out. Thank you!